# Suppress globally set 'before end axis code' in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I added a global option using `every axis/.append style={before end axis/.code={}}` to draw a box around every plot. However, I have some graphs where I would like to suppress the execution of this code. How can I do this?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Make a red box around every plot (because its beautiful)
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={before end axis/.code={
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[thin,red,solid] ({rel axis cs:0,0}) |- ({rel axis
cs:1,1}) |- cycle;
\end{scope}}}}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Already tried to use this, to no avail:
% [every axis/.append style={before end
% axis/.code={}}] 

% Don't want to have box around this graph
\begin{axis}[axis x line=none,%
axis y line=none]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just say `before end axis/.code={}` in the `axis` where you want to suppress the box.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Make a red box around every plot (because its beautiful)
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={before end axis/.code={
      \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \draw[thin,red,solid] ({rel axis cs:0,0}) |- ({rel axis
          cs:1,1}) |- cycle;
      \end{scope}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis x line=none,%
    axis y line=none]
    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Don't want to have box around this graph
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis x line=none,%
    axis y line=none,before end axis/.code={}]
    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis x line=none,%
    axis y line=none]
    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: okay, so the trick is to use it in the axis-environment options, and not as `append style`. Thanks!